# Asp.Net WebHook Sender and Recevier Flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, webhooks

Can somebody explain the flow of ASP.NET WebHook flow?
i.e. Will the sender wait for the receiver to complete its processing or the sender will just trigger the receiver method and then terminates?

I referred the below article and it shows the flow as the sender will not wait for the receiver's response, but when as its just an API endpoint call, the sender should wait for the response for the request.

[image]

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2016/01/15/sending-webhooks-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm/